# Not sure how this output is reached in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I understand why the first print statement outputs `-3 5 8 2`. But the second print outputs `4 5 8 0`. I know that the `5` and the `8` are what they are because their respective values remain unchanged, but I don't know how `w`'s value is `4` and `z`'s value becomes `0`. I think my understanding of pointers in C might be a little fuzzy.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void mysterious(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    *a = *c;
    *b = *b + *a;
    *c = *a - *b;
 }

 int main() {
    int w = 5;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 3;
    int z = 2;
    mysterious(&x, &y, &w);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z);
    mysterious(&w, &w, &z);
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", w, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the second call to mysterious, You are passing w twice. You see that, right? Now, after first statement, where *a=*c, w is 2, then you add *b which is w again, with *a which is 2.. so thats how 4. and Z will be zero, because you are basically subtracting both the W's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you translate the steps inside `mysterious` based on `*a`, `*b`, `*c` being `w`, `w`, `z` respectively then it comes out to:

```
w = z; 
w = w + w; 
z = w - w;
```

Stepping through this: `z` was `2`; so `w` becomes `2`, then `4`; and finally `z` becomes `4 - 4` which is `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply and correct answer... I now see what I wasn't seeing earlier!